# Change so that user input is not echoed to the screen

Tags: assembly, passwords, user-input, x86-16, emu8086

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    MSG DB 'Enter password: $'
    DISPLAY_MSG DB 0dh, 0ah, 'NAME: display name', 0dh, 0ah, 'ID NUMBER: display number', '$'
    ERROR_MSG DB 'Password does not match.!$'
    PASSWORD DB '123'
    BUFFER DB 4
.CODE
    MAIN PROC
        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV DS, AX
        LEA DX, MSG
        MOV AH, 9
        INT 21H ; print prompt message
        
        MOV AH, 0AH
        LEA DX, BUFFER
        INT 21H ; read input from user

        
        MOV SI, OFFSET BUFFER+2 ; skip first byte (input length)
        MOV DI, OFFSET PASSWORD
        MOV CX, 3 ; compare up to 6 characters
    CMP_LOOP:
        LODSB ; load byte from SI into AL, increment SI
        CMP AL, [DI] ; compare with password character
        JNE CMP_FAIL ; jump to failure if not equal
        INC DI ; move to next password character
        LOOP CMP_LOOP ; repeat until CX is zero
        JMP SUCCESS
    CMP_FAIL:
        ; passwords don't match, print error message
        LEA DX, ERROR_MSG
        MOV AH, 9
        INT 21H
    SUCCESS:
        ; passwords match, print success message
        LEA DX, DISPLAY_MSG
        MOV AH, 9
        INT 21H
        
        MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H ; return to DOS
    MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

How do I change this so that the user input is not displayed. I tried using `int 21h ah=08h`, but I can't seem to make it work.

I tried using `int 16h ah=00h`, and also tried creating a loop using `int 21h ah=08h`. It works but the user input is not stored within the declared password `db`.

Comment: Show the loop you tried to create with interrupt 21h function 08h.

Comment: You should allocate space for the `BUFFER` if you do use interrupt 21h function 0Ah. Your comparison loop could use `lodsb` + `scasb`, or just `cmpsb`. Setting `cx` to 3 for the comparison loop will compare the first 3 bytes of both strings, is that what you meant by "compare up to 6 characters"? Should it be success if the entered input is longer than the password but the first three bytes match? `CMP_FAIL` should end in an unconditional branch (`jmp`) to the termination call, or you could add another termination call to the failure code. Int 21h service 4Ch expects a return code in `al`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaration od `BUFFER DB 4` is not sufficient, see [BUFFERED INPUT](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm), it should be something like
`BUFFER DB 4,0,'XXXX'`. However, if you don't want to reveal the entered characters, use DOS function [CHARACTER INPUT WITHOUT ECHO](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2561.htm). In this case you don't have to store input data to memory, and just compare each obtained character with the PASSWORD template.
Instead of

```
  MOV AH, 0AH
  MOV DX, BUFFER
  INT 21H ; read input from user
```

try this:

```
       LEA SI,[PASSWORD]
       MOV CX,3       ; Size of the PASSWORD.
       MOV AH,8       ; Input one character to AL without echo.
CMP_LOOP:       
       INT 21H        ; Get one character from keyboard.
       CMP AL,[SI]    ; Does it match the template?
       JNE CMP_FAIL
       INC SI         ; Compare the next character.
       LOOP CMP_LOOP:
SUCCESS:              ; passwords match, print success message
        MOV DX, DISPLAY_MSG
        MOV AH, 9
        INT 21H
        MOV AX, 4C00H ; Terminate with errorlevel 0.
        INT 21H       ; return to DOS
CMP_FAIL:             ; passwords don't match, print error message
        MOV DX, ERROR_MSG
        MOV AH, 9
        INT 21H
        MOV AX, 4C08H ; Terminate with errorlevel 8.
        INT 21H       ; return to DOS
```

Comment: this work. thank you so much and i was able to understand what's wrong with my code.